# StreamSocket not connecting in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to connect to a TCP socket and listen for incoming connections. For testing purposes I'm trying to send an echo to port 7 and receive it in an event handler. I'm using the following code:

```
StreamSocket clientSocket;
StreamSocketListener listener;

HostName serverHost = new HostName("localhost");
await clientSocket.ConnectAsync(serverHost, "7");
await listener.BindServiceNameAsync("7");
listener.Control.QualityOfService = SocketQualityOfService.Normal;
listener.ConnectionReceived += listener_ConnectionReceived;
```

The clientSocket.ConnectAsync() line throws an exception with the message: 
**No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.**

Answer (score 0):

For this code to work you need an application (specifically an echo server) that listens for incoming connections one port 7. Operating systems today don't normally come with one.

Try setting up a [ready made](http://echovnc.sourceforge.net/fom-serve/cache/6.html) echo server on a different machine and connecting to it from the phone.